# ¿Por qué tira esta excepción: "java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3"?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public Integer modificar(Doctor doc){
    try {
        if (this.con.conectarse()) {
            this.sentencia = this.con.getCon().prepareStatement("update simame.doctor set cedula = ?, nombre = ? where cedula = ?");
            this.sentencia.setInt(1, doc.getCedula());
            this.sentencia.setString(2, doc.getNombre());
            this.sentencia.executeUpdate();
            this.con.desconectarse();
            return 0; // todo bien
        }else{
        return 1; // NO se Conecto
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 2; // Existe un error
    }
}
```

Pero presenta esta excepcion:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
> ```

Comment: Nota aparte. No creo que sea buena idea de usar `con` y `sentencia` como variables globales. Te va a causar problemas mas adelante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No value specified for parameter 3

```
this.sentencia.setInt(1, doc.getCedula());
this.sentencia.setString(2, doc.getNombre());
//Aqui te falta algo
this.sentencia.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

No le estas dando el valor a la variable **cedula** para que pueda comparar.

```
public Integer modificar(Doctor doc, int cedula){ // **<---Aqui podrias tomar el valor un valor y agregarlo como parametro**
    try {
        if (this.con.conectarse()) {
            this.sentencia = this.con.getCon().prepareStatement("update simame.doctor set cedula = ?, nombre = ? where cedula = 3423"); **<---Aqui podrias asignar un valor**
            this.sentencia.setInt(1, doc.getCedula());
            this.sentencia.setString(2, doc.getNombre());
            this.sentencia.executeUpdate();
            this.con.desconectarse();
            return 0; // todo bien
        }else{
        return 1; // NO se Conecto
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 2; // Existe un error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer:

```
this.sentencia.setInt(1, doc.getCedula());
this.sentencia.setString(2, doc.getNombre());
```

...estás asignando los valores para los parámetros siguientes:

```sql
set cedula = ?, nombre = ?
```

Pero no le has suministrado el tercer parámetro necesario para la parte siguiente de la consulta:

```sql
where cedula = ?
```

Por eso recibes el error.

Pero siendo que `cedula` parece ser tu llave primaria, no tiene sentido que trates de modificarla. Lo mas lógico es que modifiques tu `UPDATE` quitándole el `set cedula = ?` de modo que quede así:

```sql
update simame.doctor set nombre = ? where cedula = ?
```

Y entonces, ahora sí, solo necesitas setear los 2 parámetros, pero en el orden inverso:

```
this.sentencia.setString(1, doc.getNombre());
this.sentencia.setInt(2, doc.getCedula());
```

Comment: Gracias, entendí mejor su  respuesta y la explicación

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que la consulta está esperando 3 parámetros:

```
this.sentencia = this.con.getCon().prepareStatement("update simame.doctor set cedula = ?, nombre = ? where cedula = ?");
```

Y tu solamente estas seteando dos de ellos:

```
this.sentencia.setInt(1, doc.getCedula());
this.sentencia.setString(2, doc.getNombre());
```

Tendrías que volver a setear cedula en el último parámetro.